# copy pointer to pointer (an array containting pointer) to another one

Tags: c

I tried to copy a pointer to pointer (an array containing pointer) but when I ran it get weird result:
here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

#pragma warning(disable:4996)
void mycopy(char *c[], char *o[], int olen);
char *alloc(int n);

int main() {
    char *o[] = { "12", "13", "14" };
    char *c[3];
    mycopy(c, o, 3);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", o[i]);
        printf("%s\n", c[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}

void mycopy(char *c[], char *o[], int olen) {
    char *t;
    for (int i = 0; i < olen; i++) {
        //printf("%d\n", strlen(o[i]));
        if ((t = alloc(strlen(o[i]))) == NULL) {
            printf("don't use copy cause there isn't enough space\n");
            return;
        }
        //printf("%s\n", o[i]);
        strcpy(t, o[i]);
        //printf("%s\n", t);
        *c++ = t;
    }
}

#define MAXBUF 1000000
char buf[MAXBUF]; /* Maximum space which we can allocate */
char *bufc = buf;

/* alloc: allocate space to a pointer */
char *alloc(int n) {
    if (buf + MAXBUF - bufc >= n) {
        bufc += n;
        return bufc - n;
    }
    else
        return 0;
}
```

weirdly the result for c is:
121314   1314   14
while I checked the process by commented printfs in mycopy function and every thing seems right.
is there anyway other way to copy ?
oh and I'm a beginner in c so while I tried to solve an example in K&R2 this problem came up to me.

Comment: You are allocating one less than what you need. You need an additional character for the terminating null character. Use `alloc(strlen(o[i]) + 1)`.

Comment: oh you are right R Sahu. thanks :)

Comment: sorry thought C and C++ are related. but it seems I was wrong

Answer (score 0):

```
t = alloc(strlen(o[i]))
```

But the length of a string is `strlen+1`, because you need one byte for the trailing nul terminator.

If you're not sure, just use `strdup` instead.

NB. You can see exactly *why* this gives the output it does, by examining the address stored in each of your three pointers. Either use your debugger, or just print the addresses.

Answer (score 0):

Each element is in the form: '1' '2' '\0' (the last is the terminator).

Your buffer at the end contains: ['1', '2', '1', '3', '1', '4', '\0', ..........] and when you print you're actually printing from the beginning of your current element up to the first '\0'. Each time you overwrite the last '\0' (printf stops there). You just should "alloc(strlen(o[i] + 1)".